# Expectation of a special form of quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, quadratic-forms

Let $\mathbf x$ be a $n\times1$ random variable, $\mathbf s$ be a vector of size $3\times 1$ and $A$, $M_1$, $M_2$ and $M_3$ be  $n\times n$ matrices. What is the following expectation with respect to $\mathbf x$

$$ y =E_x \Big[\parallel A\mathbf x+[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x]\mathbf s\parallel ^2\Big] $$

My work:
$$y =E_x \Bigg[\bigg( A\mathbf x+\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]\mathbf s\bigg)^T
\bigg(A\mathbf x+\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]\mathbf s\bigg)\Bigg]  $$

$$=E_x \Bigg[
\mathbf x^TA^TA\mathbf x+
\mathbf x^TA^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]\mathbf s+
s^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]^TA\mathbf x+
s^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]\mathbf s
\Bigg] $$

$$=E_x \Big[\mathbf x^TA^TA\mathbf x\Big]+
E_x \Bigg[\mathbf x^TA^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]\mathbf s\Bigg]+
E_x \Bigg[s^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]^TA\mathbf x\Bigg]+
E_x \Bigg[s^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]\mathbf s
\Bigg]$$

Since $\mathbf x^TA^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]\mathbf s = s^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]^TA\mathbf x$,

$$ y = E_x \Big[\mathbf x^TA^TA\mathbf x\Big]+
2E_x \Bigg[\mathbf x^TA^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]\mathbf s\Bigg]+
E_x \Bigg[s^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]^T\bigg[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x\bigg]\mathbf s
\Bigg]\tag{1}$$

I know if $\Lambda$ be a symmetric matrix,
$$E_x[\mathbf x^T\Lambda \mathbf x] = \mu_x^T\Lambda \mu_x + tr(\Lambda\Sigma_x )\tag2$$
where $\mu_x = E[\mathbf x]$ and $\Sigma_x = Var(\mathbf x)$.
Using $(2)$, the first term of $(1)$ will be

$$E_x \Big[\mathbf x^TA^TA\mathbf x\Big] = \mu_xA^TA\mu_x+tr(A^TA\Sigma_x)\tag{3}$$
But I have no idea to go on. I don't know if $A^TM_i$ is symmetric or not.
Can you help me assuming (i) $A^TM_i$ is symmetric, (ii) $A^TM_i$ is not symmetric?
Thanks.

Comment: $[M_1\mathbf{x},M_2\mathbf{x}, M_3\mathbf{x}]$ is $3 \times 1$, so $[M_1\mathbf{x},M_2\mathbf{x}, M_3\mathbf{x}]\mathbf{s}$ is undefined. Do you see this?

Comment: @Clarinetist please note that $[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x]$ is $n \times 3$ and $[M_1\mathbf x, M_2\mathbf x, M_3\mathbf x]\mathbf s$ is $n\times 1$.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will try this out.